# Clearing confusion about no-break power requirement

Tags: power-supply, ups

I'm considering purchasing a no-break for my Intel NUC8i7HNK. I'm looking at a model that says that the power required by all connected appliances shouldn't exceed 600 VA (same as W, I suppose). The NUC's power supply says that it's input is 100–240 V; 3,5 A. That should be 770 W, since my power grid is in 220 V. But the output is listed as 19,5 V; 11,8 A; 230 W.

Why this difference of 540 W between input and output? Can I use this no-break or not?

Comment: What's a no break?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Probably a mini UPS.

Comment: 600 Volt-Amps is absolutely NOT the same thing as Watts. Volt-Amps has a power factor which you haven’t provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure for input is the maximum, it is a rating (maximum), not a consumption figure.

- It is listing the maximum current (which is for the lowest voltage - 100V)  It is not going to draw 3.5A, no matter what voltage is presented to it.  So That's 350W.
- There is a safety factor to ensure that the rating is not under-quoted.
- There is provision for a peak or inrush or switching current that is higher than the steady state.
- Finally, there are losses.

You will be fine using that no-break.